# Get Notification when New Contact is added to Device on Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I need to set Callback function for New Contact added to Device on Windows Mobile.

I want to get notification when someone adds contacts to mobile device. I am using VS 2008 with C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook.ContactCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.contactcollection_members.aspx) has a [`ListChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.contactcollection_events.aspx).  Is that what you're after?

**EDIT**

I think what you want is available in [this library I published](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/CommentView,guid,0a7746f3-b62b-4a06-aa4a-0bbe2ec6ba05.aspx) a couple years back.

Comment: No. That will be called only when Contact is added programatically. I want to get notification even if Contact is added directly in Outlook (from device) outside of my application. I have found one useful link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms862902.aspx) but that is in unmanaged code. I don't know how to use it in C#. Can you help me to call it from C#? Kind of creating wrapper?